# ggplot2 add manual bar to existing plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a single, manual bar to the existing area (ribbon) plot. Ideally I just wanted to specify the x (position) and y (value) for the bar.

```
ExampleData <- data.frame(myID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),PU=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
MyPlot <- ggplot(ExampleData,aes(x=myID))
MyPlot <- MyPlot + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=PU), fill="lightgray", color="darkgray", size=1)
MyPlot <- MyPlot + geom_col(aes(x=4,y=40), color="red", linetype="solid", size=1)
MyPlot
```

It is almost working, but for some reason the value of 40 is becoming 400, and ideally I should be able to specify the width of the bar (should be half of what we see below).

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Since you aren't overriding the data argument in the `geom_col` layer, it is repeating the x,y values 10 times. Probably you'd be better off just using `geom_rect()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something more like this?

```
ExampleData <- data.frame(myID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                          PU=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
bar <- data.frame(xmin = 4,xmax= 4.5,ymin = 0,ymax = 40)
ggplot() + 
    geom_ribbon(data = ExampleData,
                aes(x = myID,ymin=0, ymax=PU), 
                fill="lightgray", 
                color="darkgray", size=1) + 
    geom_rect(data = bar,
              aes(xmin = xmin,xmax = xmax,ymin = ymin,ymax = ymax),
              color = "red")
```

The 40 vs 400 issue you mention happens when you specify a data frame at the top `ggplot()` level and then try to add layers where all the aesthetics are intended to be "set" rather than "mapped". The most common case when this happens is when people are adding text labels and you end up with many many copies of each text label plotted on top of each other.

In this case, ggplot is trying to interpret the x and y values you give `geom_col` in the context of `ExampleData`, and so ends up repeating those single values 10 times and stacking the resulting bars.